# Having multiple values in Wordpress theme customization dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress

[image]

In my theme customization menu, I want to have a section for footer options. Which is number of columns as well as the header titles for each column. What I have so far is the image, and all the options become saved as the same thing. How can I change it so each section is a different value?

My code in functions.php:

```
/*
Footer headers and number of columns
*/
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'footer_options', array(
  'title' => __( 'Footer column options', 'Universal Theme'),
  'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
  'description' => __( 'Update footer options')
));

$wp_customize->add_section( 'footer_options', array(
  'title' => __( 'Footer options', 'Universal Theme' ),
  'capability' => 'edit_theme_options'
));

$wp_customize->add_control( 'footer_options', array(
  'settings' => 'footer_options',
  'section' => 'footer_options',
  'type' => 'radio',
  'choices' => array(
    1 => __( '1' ),
    2 => __( '2' ),
    3 => __( '3' ),
    4 => __( '4' ),
    5 => __( '5' ),
    6 => __( '6' )
  ),
  'label' => __( 'Number of columns' )
));

$wp_customize->add_control( 'footer_options_header1', array(
  'settings' => 'footer_options',
  'section' => 'footer_options',
  'type' => 'text',
  'label' => __( 'Footer header 1' )
));

$wp_customize->add_control( 'footer_options_header2', array(
  'settings' => 'footer_options',
  'section' => 'footer_options',
  'type' => 'text',
  'label' => __( 'Footer header 2' )
));

$wp_customize->add_control( 'footer_options_header3', array(
  'settings' => 'footer_options',
  'section' => 'footer_options',
  'type' => 'text',
  'label' => __( 'Footer header 3' )
));

$wp_customize->add_control( 'footer_options_header4', array(
  'settings' => 'footer_options',
  'section' => 'footer_options',
  'type' => 'text',
  'label' => __( 'Footer header 4' )
));

$wp_customize->add_control( 'footer_options_header5', array(
  'settings' => 'footer_options',
  'section' => 'footer_options',
  'type' => 'text',
  'label' => __( 'Footer header 5' )
));

$wp_customize->add_control( 'footer_options_header6', array(
  'settings' => 'footer_options',
  'section' => 'footer_options',
  'type' => 'text',
  'label' => __( 'Footer header 6' )
));
```

All of it is in a function that is placed in an add_action of 'customize_register'

What changes do I need for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

We can use same section but we need to add setting for every control. right now you are using same **setting ID** for all control. so every value will store in **footer_options**.

Use like:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting( 'footer_options_one', array(
  'title' => __( 'Footer column options', 'Universal Theme'),
  'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
      'description' => __( 'Update footer options')
));


$wp_customize->add_setting( 'footer_options_two', array(
  'title' => __( 'Footer column options', 'Universal Theme'),
  'capability' => 'edit_theme_options',
      'description' => __( 'Update footer options')
));
```

To learn it, you can visits:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/customize_register